# Conditional simulating based on matches and probability

Tags: r

Two matrices

```
df_A = matrix(, nrow = 5, ncol = 3)
df_A[,1] = c(0, 0, 1, -1, 1)
df_A[,2] = c(0, 1, -1, 0, -1)
df_A[,3] = c(1, 0, -1, 1, 1)
df_B = matrix(, nrow = 5, ncol = 3)
df_B[,1] = c(1, -1, 0, 0, 1)
```

I want to simulate columns 2 and 3 for df_B based on a few conditions. If the value of df_A is zero, the value for df_B does not change. For example, the first two values for df_B should not change for the first iteration because the first two values for df_A are zero. If the value of df_A is one or negative one, then the respective value for df_B will take on that value given a certain probability (20% in this example). For example, if df_A is negative one and df_B is zero (or one), the respective value for df_B will become negative one 20% of the time.

I know the following is incorrect but here is what I have so far:

```
belief_change = function(x){
  if (df_A[x] = -1 & df_B[x] != -1 & sample(1:2, 1, prob = c(0.2, 0.8) = 1))
    df_B[x+1] = df_A[x]
  else
    df_B[x+1] = df_B[x]
  if (df_A[x] = 1 & df_B[x] != 1 & sample(1:2, 1, prob = c(0.2, 0.8) = 1))
    df_B[x+1] = df_A[x]
  else
    df_B[x+1] = df_B[x]
  if (df_A[x] = 0)
    df_B[x+1] = df_B[x]
}
```

I'm using the sample function here to help generate a probability. I also need to put this into a for-loop eventually.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code. First, the correct logical equality operator is `==` not `=`. Second, you put `= 1` inside the call to `sample`. Third, if you really want to affect the environment outside where the function is called (i.e. to change `df_B` by calling your function, you need to use the deep assignment operator `<<-`, not `=` or `<-`. You can read more about this [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html).

Here is a version of your code that works; see if it does what you want it to do.

```
belief_change <- function(x) {
  if (df_A[x] == -1 & df_B[x] != -1 & sample(1:2, 1, prob = c(0.2, 0.8)) == 1)
    df_B[x+1] <<- df_A[x]
  else
    df_B[x+1] <<- df_B[x]

  if (df_A[x] == 1 & df_B[x] != 1 & sample(1:2, 1, prob = c(0.2, 0.8)) == 1)
    df_B[x+1] <<- df_A[x]
  else
    df_B[x+1] <<- df_B[x]

  if (df_A[x] == 0)
    df_B[x+1] <<- df_B[x]
}
```